# Extracting the Hour from A imported CSV file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

Probably a silly question but in matlab I have imported CSV data. One of the columns I have imported into my workspace is a timestamp and it is of the format "4568x1 cell" (stored as strings). It is of the format

```
timestamp(1) = 'Reading time"
timestamp(2) = '2014-12-19 00:00:43 UTC'
timestamp(3) = '2014-12-19 00:01:43 UTC'
```

,etc How do I just get the hour so I get 00,01,etc and store it in a new array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use `datevec` here, after some trimming:

```
timestamp(1) = []; % remove the first line
timestamp = cell2mat(timestamp); % now all are same length can do this
timestamp = timestamp(:,1:end-4); % remove UTC part
timevec = datevec(timestamp); % probably don't need format specifier
```

`time_date` should now be a 4567 x 6 matrix (since we removed one row), where the columns are year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.  Therefore for the hours we just need this:

```
hours = time_date(:,4);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`datenum`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html) to convert the date string to a numerical format, e.g.

```
timestamp{2} = '2014-12-19 00:00:43 UTC'; % use curly braces as cell array
timestamp{3} = '2014-12-19 00:01:43 UTC';
date_num(1) = datenum(timestamp{2}(1:end-4),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'); % remove the ' UTC' characters at the end of the string
date_num(2) = datenum(timestamp{3}(1:end-4),'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS'); % remove the ' UTC' characters at the end of the string
% etc... (use a for loop to go through all elements of the cell array) 
hh = [0 diff(date_num)*24*60]; % elapsed time in hours, taking the first time stamp as reference
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the hour consists of *digits surrounded by `:` symbols*, you could easily apply a [regular expression](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) with [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), and then convert the detected strings into numbers:

```
%// Data
timestamp{1} = 'Reading time';
timestamp{2} = '2014-12-19 00:00:43 UTC';
timestamp{3} = '2014-12-19 00:01:43 UTC';

%// Get hours as a cell array of cells containing strings:
hours_cells = regexp(timestamp(2:end), '(?<=:)(\d+)(?=:)', 'match'); %// no title

%// Convert to numbers:
hours = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x{1}), hours_cells);
```

If the *character structure is fixed* (each number includes left zero padding to equalize width), you can identify the positions of the  hour (characters 15 and 16 in this case) and do it more simply:

```
hours = cellfun(@(x) str2num(x([15 16])), timestamp(2:end));
```

or, possibly faster,

```
hours = cellfun(@(x) (x([15 16])-48)*[10;1], timestamp(2:end));
%// 48 is ASCII for '0'
```